# PL SQL Function -compilation errors

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to pl sql ,been trying to execute this function but getting compilation errors.

```
create or replace function "rural_finance" return number is  
total number(13) :=0;
begin
select
(select  "RURAL FINANCE " from rural_master_view1 t where load_date='apr-15' and activity='FINANCE_AMOUNT')
-
(select  "RURAL FINANCE " from rural_master_view1 t where load_date='may-15' and activity='FINANCE_AMOUNT')
-
(select sum(disb_amount)
           from retail_disbursal
          where load_date = 'may-15'
            and subproduct_name = 'TRACTOR') into total from dual
 return total ;
end rural_finance;
```

Unfortunately, my pl-sql developer somehow is not displaying those errors ,so i'm not able to figure out the issue.

Also,when trying to recompile it ,it says 'object does not exist'  or already deleted.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `;` after dual at least.

Comment: If you are using [PL/SQL Developer](https://www.allroundautomations.com/plsqldev.html), make sure you are using a Program window to edit and compile your code, as this will highlight compilation errors and their source lines etc.

Comment: Are the `load_date` columns actual dates (datatype `date`) or character strings (datatype `varchar2`)? Also, double-quotes mean "use this object name exactly as I have typed it regardless of any standard object naming rules or common sense", so `"RURAL FINANCE "` refers to a column named exactly that, complete with the two spaces. I hope you don't have a column named `"RURAL FINANCE "`.

Comment: I got the issue,ofcourse a ';' after dual is an issue but before that ,i was using Quote identifier in my function name.When i removed the quotes i got the actual error for that ';' .

Answer (score 0):

First:
If You use table alias (here: "t") then:

```
 from rural_master_view1 t where t.load_date='apr-15' and t.activity='FINANCE_AMOUNT
```

and as was said - ";" after dual:

```
into total from dual**;**
```